# How do you have multiple Regular Expression Extractors running in one test plan?

Tags: jmeter, post-processor

I'm trying to extract variables returned from one HTTP request, use them in a second HTTP request then extract the variables returned from the second HTTP request.

I then need to use both the first extracted and second extracted variables in a third HTTP request.

I can extract the variables from the first HTTP request and use these in the second HTTP request but cant seem to get the variables extracted from the second HTTP request to then use in the third HTTP request.

Is it even possible to do this?
This is my current set up

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be straightforward and possible as long as both extractors are going into unique variable names.  The Debug Postprocessor will show you the values stored in each variable after a test run. What do you see in those in the context of the third http request?

Comment: Thanks Paul! Turns out i was just missing \{.* off the start of my second lot (Add Client Lead) of regular expressions.